# Reinstall Ubuntu (With Windows 7)

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-7

I successfully messed up Ubuntu. Now, I need to reinstall it. But Windows 7 is also installed on my computer, and it is the main OS.
Now I booted up into the Ubuntu 13.04 installation DVD, and one of the options is to "Reinstall Ubuntu 13.04". I need to reinstall Ubuntu, but I don't want to lose my Windows 7 OS from the reinstallation. I just wanted to make sure and be clear that it is okay to reinstall Ubuntu*. Thanks!

*That is: Ubuntu will be reinstalled in the right partition from its previous installation, and my Windows 7 OS will take no harm.

Comment: Oh fail I just found out that the third option is to erase EVERYTHING and reinstall. From this information given, and using logic, the reinstall Ubuntu 13.04 is safe to do. I just need proof.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to really freshly install new Ubuntu why bother with such option, I usually just erasing my old Ubuntu partition and starting new partition and do fresh install again with dual boot as usual. Hope can help. Sorry just never trying the `reinstall Ubuntu` option.

Comment: Yes, use EXT4 for the filesystem, and mount at "/". Also, write the bootloader in the same partition as the Ubuntu partition. Choose to format the partition as well.

Comment: It is. So did it done good?